# iOS: popover over popover?

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-experience, popover

I'm developing a iPad app which has a popover which appears to show you a list of items. I need the ability to delete one of the items, so I'm considering adding the ability to press-and-hold (a.k.a. long tap) on one of the list items which would show another popover for that item, with an action list showing a delete button.

Two questions:

- In terms of iPad UX, is this a good idea? Haven't seen it anywhere, and I guess it could be a little confusing...but how else can I do this?
- Is this possible, code wise? I haven't tried it, but I am still pretty new to iOS development so I could see myself fumbling round for hours before finding out there's a technical reason why it's not possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at how deleting items is performed in Mail.app

Comment: Good point. I guess the inline delete button is the iOS convention, I should probably stick to that. Thanks!

Comment: if someone answers your question (such as fzwo), remember to mark their answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark

Comment: @RyanR, I hadn't forgotten, I was waiting for other opinions still to decide on what the best answer was. IMO this isn't a question which necessarily has a "right" answer.

Comment: @user700774 Yes, it does have a right answer (or, rather, two, since you asked two questions): It's possible (I was wrong in my original answer, since edited), but Apple says "don't do it" in the iOS HIG, as per Wayne Hartman's comment. That *is* the definitive answer. Also, UIActionSheets are there for exactly this sort of scenario: As a kind of confirmation dialogue when manipulating something inside a popover.

Comment: @fzwo, I was moreso referring to other alternatives for this kind of interaction - that doesn't necessarily have a "right" answer. All the feedback has been helpful though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a good idea, <s>and I don't think it's possible</s> even though it's possible.

Apple's Human Interface Guidelines clearly state that [you should not do it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ContentViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW19). This is as definitive an answer as there can be regarding UX.

For inspiration on how to delete items without requiring a popover, look at how `UITableView` does it, for instance.

Often, you'll have an *Edit* button in the top toolbar inside the popover to trigger edit mode.

If you want some kind of confirmation dialog, use `UIActionSheet`. They look good and work well enough, especially in popovers. In your case, I think these are the way to go.

Comment: +1 The Human Interface Guidelines suggest not having popovers on top of popovers.  Only one should be present at a time. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW40

Comment: Presenting popovers from popovers is definitely _possible_ (I've done it).  It's just a bad idea.